# Assertion error when using warpAffine in python/opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I am translating an image `im` by `tx` and `ty` pixels.

```py
def translate(im, tx, ty):
    height, width = im.shape[:2]
    transform_matrix = np.array([[1, 0, tx], [0, 1, ty]])
    translation = cv2.warpAffine(src=im, M=transform_matrix, dsize=(width, height))
```

However, it fails with the following error,

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) /Users/runner/work/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp:2604: error: (-215:Assertion failed) (M0.type() == CV_32F || M0.type() == CV_64F) && M0.rows == 2 && M0.cols == 3 in function 'warpAffine'
```

I did double check that my image is in `int` type and has the correct dimensions, but couldn't figure out which part is the problem.

Comment: Make your array into an array of floats. `np.array([[1, 0, tx], [0, 1, ty]]).astype(np.float64)`

Comment: or just `np.float64([...])`

Comment: The error message says it, the matrix must be 2x3 with float or double elements. It does not complain about the type of the image.